# Consume external API and performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working a Ruby on Rails project that consumes data through some external API.

This API allows me to get a list of cars and display them on my single webpage.

I created a model that holds all methods related to this API.
The controller uses list_cars method from the model to forward the data to the view.

This is the model dedicated to the API calls:

```
class CarsApi
  @base_uri = 'https://api.greatcars.com/v1/'

  def self.list_cars
    cars = Array.new
    response = HTTParty.get(@base_uri + 'cars',
                            headers: {
                              'Authorization' => 'Token token=' + ENV['GREATCARS_API_TOKEN'],
                              'X-Api-Version' => ENV["GREATCARS_API_VERSION"]
                            })

    response["data"].each_with_index do |(key, value), index|
      id = response["data"][index]["id"]
      make = response["data"][index]["attributes"]["make"]
      store = get_store(id)
      location = get_location(id)
      model = response["data"][index]["attributes"]["model"]

      if response["data"][index]["attributes"]["status"] == "on sale"
        cars << Job.new(id, make, store, location, model)
      end
    end

    cars
  end

  def self.get_store(job_id)
    store = ''
    response_related_store = HTTParty.get(@base_uri + 'cars/' + job_id + "/relationships/store",
                                               headers: {
                                                 'Authorization' => 'Token token=' + ENV['GREATCARS_API_TOKEN'],
                                                 'X-Api-Version' => ENV["GREATCARS_API_VERSION"]
                                               })

    if response_related_store["data"]
      store_id = response_related_store["data"]["id"]
      response_store = HTTParty.get(@base_uri + 'stores/' + store_id,
                                         headers: {
                                           'Authorization' => 'Token token=' + ENV['GREATCARS_API_TOKEN'],
                                           'X-Api-Version' => ENV["GREATCARS_API_VERSION"]
                                         })
      store = response_store["data"]["attributes"]["name"]
    end

    store
  end

  def self.get_location(job_id)
    address, city, country, zip, lat, long = ''
    response_related_location = HTTParty.get(@base_uri + 'cars/' + job_id + "/relationships/location",
                                               headers: {
                                                 'Authorization' => 'Token token=' + ENV['GREATCARS_API_TOKEN'],
                                                 'X-Api-Version' => ENV["GREATCARS_API_VERSION"]
                                               })
    if response_related_location["data"]
      location_id = response_related_location["data"]["id"]
      response_location = HTTParty.get(@base_uri + 'locations/' + location_id,
                                         headers: {
                                           'Authorization' => 'Token token=' + ENV['GREATCARS_API_TOKEN'],
                                           'X-Api-Version' => ENV["GREATCARS_API_VERSION"]
                                         })
      if response_location["data"]["attributes"]["address"]
        address = response_location["data"]["attributes"]["address"]
      end
      if response_location["data"]["attributes"]["city"]
        city = response_location["data"]["attributes"]["city"]
      end
      if response_location["data"]["attributes"]["country"]
        country = response_location["data"]["attributes"]["country"]
      end
      if response_location["data"]["attributes"]["zip"]
        zip = response_location["data"]["attributes"]["zip"]
      end
      if response_location["data"]["attributes"]["lat"]
        lat = response_location["data"]["attributes"]["lat"]
      end
      if response_location["data"]["attributes"]["long"]
        long = response_location["data"]["attributes"]["long"]
      end
    end

    Location.new(address, city, country, zip, lat, long)
  end
end
```

It takes... 1 minute and 10 secondes to load my home page!
I wonder if there is a better way to do this and improve performances.

Comment: are you directly calling this list_cars every time you make the request?.  Since you have created a model to save the api response I would suggest to do write a background task to populate the car model. and your api could fetch the data from your Database

Comment: It's not an ActiveRecord model but a Plain Old Ruby Object so yes, it seems this gets called for every request.

Answer (score 0):

> It takes... 1 minute and 10 seconds to load my home page! I wonder if there is a better way to do this and improve performances.

If you want to improve the performance of some piece of code, the first thing you should always do is add some instrumentation. It seems you already have some metric how long loading the whole page takes but you need to figure out now WHAT is actually taking long. There are many great gems and services out there which can help you.

### Services:

- https://newrelic.com/
- https://www.skylight.io/
- https://www.datadoghq.com/

### Gems

- https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler
- https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-rails
- Or just add some plain old logging

### N+1 request

One assumption why this is slow could be that you do for every car FOUR additional requests to fetch the store and location. This means if you display 10 jobs on your homepage you would need to do 50 API requests. Even if each request just takes ~1 second it's almost one minute.

One simple idea is to cache the additional resources in a lookup table. I'm not sure how many jobs would share the same store and location though so not sure how much it would actually safe.

This could be a simple lookup table like:

```rb
class Store
  cattr_reader :table do
   {}
  end

  class << self
    def self.find(id)
      self.class.table[id] ||= fetch_store(id)
    end

    private
    
    def fetch_store(id)
      # copy code here to fetch store from API
    end
  end
end
```

This way, if several jobs have the same location / store you only do one request.

### Lazy load

This depends on the design of the page but you could lazy load additional information like location and store.

One thing many pages do is to display a placeholder or [dominant colour](https://manu.ninja/dominant-colors-for-lazy-loading-images/) and lazy load further content with Java Script.

Another idea could be load store and location when scrolling or hovering but this depends a bit on the design of your page.

### Pagination / Limit

Maybe you're also requesting too many items from the API. See if the API has some options to limit the number of items you request e.g. `https://api.greatcars.com/v1/cars/limit=10&page=1`

But as said, even if this is limited to 10 items you would end up with 50 requests in total. So until you fix the first issue, this won't have much impact.

### General Caching

Generally I think it's not a good idea to always send an API request for each request you page gets. You could introduce some caching to e.g. only do an API request once every x minutes / hour / day.

This could be as simple as just storing in a class variable or using memcached / Redis / Database.

Comment: Instead of caching the request (which would mean that the first request to the server would take as much time as it is currently taking), the data should be persisted on a background process.

Comment: This is still some sort of a cache but definitely a possibility. Storing in a database makes it more difficult to invalidate your cache though.

Comment: `which would mean that the first request to the server would take as much time as it is currently taking` not necessarily if they can improve the n+1 query. I don't expect each car is at a different store and there should be some overlap and drastically reduce the number of requests required.

Comment: Persistency does not necessarily imply persistency inside a relational database. I'm assuming that given the nature of his application, he needs n+1 queries to show the whole data in some kind of search, even if there's a reduction in the number of requests. Will caching the first request be enough? Is it acceptable if the first request takes, for example, 1 minute? It all depends on how fast the response to the user should be. I am assuming that OP needs the server to answer ASAP. In this approach I would opt for "caching" (doesn't matter where) on the background as a pessimistic measure.

Comment: First thanks for the suggestions Christian!

One thing important that I discovered is that the API actually supports parameters that allow to include extra data in the response. This reduced right away the time to load all the information from 1m10 to 2 seconds...

But even 2 seconds was still too slow, so I cached the data on a database as you suggested. The data is not so critical, so it gets updated every one hour.

Comment: Great! If you're happy with the answer please consider accepting and upvoting it.